# How to pivot from wide to long format based on multiple column name separators?

Tags: r, tidyr

I understand there have been similar posts, but I'm a little confused on how I can use `pivot_longer` to transform my own data from wide to long format. The code below creates a mock dataset that's structured similar to my real data.

```
    library(tidyverse)
    
## Dummy data.

# ID Variables.

part <- rep(rep(paste0("P", c(1:2)), each = 20, times = 2))
type <- rep(c("pre", "post"), each = 10, times = 4)
sp <- rep(c("slow", "mod"), each = 40)

# Values

var1_site1_L <- rep(c(1, NA), each = 5, times = 8)
var1_site1_R <- rep(c(1, NA), each = 5, times = 8)
var1_site1_ALL <- rep(1, times = 80)
var1_site1_ALL_M <- rep(c(1, rep(NA, times = 9)), times = 8)

var2_site2_L <- rep(c(1, NA), each = 5, times = 8)
var2_site2_R <- rep(c(1, NA), each = 5, times = 8)
var2_site2_ALL <- rep(1, times = 80)
var2_site2_ALL_M <- rep(c(1, rep(NA, times = 9)), times = 8)


dat <- data.frame(part, type, sp, var1_site1_L, var1_site1_R, var1_site1_ALL,
                  var1_site1_ALL_M, var2_site2_L, var2_site2_R, var2_site2_ALL,
                  var2_site2_ALL_M)
```

I want to be able to keep the variables `part`, `type` and `sp` as ID variables, but add the unique column name separators as additional ID variables with the specific value in the final column. For example, I'd like the result to be something similar to (***note this is only a very basic example and, of course, there will be many more observations, including those NA values in the value column***):

```
    par     type     sp     var     site     side     misc     value
    p1      pre      slow   var1    site1    L        NA       1
    p1      pre      slow   var1    site1    R        NA       1
    p1      pre      slow   var1    site1    ALL      NA       1
    p1      pre      slow   var1    site1    ALL      M        1
```

I know this is a pretty unique data structure. I'm particularly stuck on how to deal with the fourth column name separator (`M`) in some instances (cases where there is only a single value per ID variables).

I got up to the below code which I know needs a bit of work if I'm to achieve the result I'm after.

```
long <- dat %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = c(1:3),
               names_to = c("var", "site", "side", "misc"),
               names_sep = "_")
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I experimented with the results I produced in the earlier solution and pivot_wider then pivot_longer and found how to make it work for pivot_longer.Your original approach was very close.

```
 dat %>%
    pivot_longer(
        cols = !c(part, type, sp),
        names_to = c("var", "site", "side", "misc"),
        names_sep = "_",
        values_to = "value"
    )

  part  type  sp    var   site  side  misc  value
   <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <dbl>
 1 P1    pre   slow  var1  site1 L     NA        1
 2 P1    pre   slow  var1  site1 R     NA        1
 3 P1    pre   slow  var1  site1 ALL   NA        1
 4 P1    pre   slow  var1  site1 ALL   M         1
 5 P1    pre   slow  var2  site2 L     NA        1
 6 P1    pre   slow  var2  site2 R     NA        1
 7 P1    pre   slow  var2  site2 ALL   NA        1
 8 P1    pre   slow  var2  site2 ALL   M         1
 9 P1    pre   slow  var1  site1 L     NA        1
10 P1    pre   slow  var1  site1 R     NA        1
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can get there with pivot_longer, but try this.

```
library(stringr)

results <- data.frame()

for (x in 4:length(dat)){

    names <- names(dat[,c(1:3,x)])
    
    res <- dat %>%
        mutate(id = 1:nrow(dat)) %>%
        select(id, names) %>%
        mutate(var = str_extract(names[4],"var\\d"),
               site = str_extract(names[4],"site\\d"),
               side = str_extract(names[4],"L|R|ALL"),
               misc = str_extract(names[4],"[M]"),
               misc = ifelse(is.na(misc), "NA", misc)) %>%
        rename("value" = 5) %>%
        select(id, part, type, sp, var, site, side, misc, value)
    

    
    results <- rbind(results, res)
}

head(results %>% arrange(id) %>% select(-id))

  part type   sp  var  site side misc value
1   P1  pre slow var1 site1    L   NA     1
2   P1  pre slow var1 site1    R   NA     1
3   P1  pre slow var1 site1  ALL   NA     1
4   P1  pre slow var1 site1  ALL    M     1
5   P1  pre slow var2 site2    L   NA     1
6   P1  pre slow var2 site2    R   NA     1
```

Answer (score 1):

```
dat %>%
  pivot_longer(starts_with('var')) %>%
  separate(name, c('var', 'site', 'side', 'misc'), fill = 'right')

# A tibble: 640 x 8
   part  type  sp    var   site  side  misc  value
   <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <dbl>
 1 P1    pre   slow  var1  site1 L     NA        1
 2 P1    pre   slow  var1  site1 R     NA        1
 3 P1    pre   slow  var1  site1 ALL   NA        1
 4 P1    pre   slow  var1  site1 ALL   M         1
 5 P1    pre   slow  var2  site2 L     NA        1
 6 P1    pre   slow  var2  site2 R     NA        1
 7 P1    pre   slow  var2  site2 ALL   NA        1
 8 P1    pre   slow  var2  site2 ALL   M         1
 9 P1    pre   slow  var1  site1 L     NA        1
10 P1    pre   slow  var1  site1 R     NA        1
# ... with 630 more rows
```